# json map style parsing failed in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I want to create a JSON file to style my google map but I get this message: E/Google Maps Android API: Map style parsing failed: org.json.JSONException: Value res of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
E/MapsActivityRaw: Style parsing failed. Any help?
[Here is my code example where I have the method with JSON creation and on left side you see the raw package where the JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASJsS.png)

[Here is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxYo.png)

I used Google platform mapstyle.withgoogle.com. But the thing that I'm not sure about, that I created a Text Document then changed the ending to .json, copied the JSON code from google platform and put it there and then copied the file and put it in android studio. Because I couldn't know how to create a JSON file in android studio. I don't know if it sounds the right way to do that?

Comment: Do you create JSON manually or using https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ ?

Comment: I'm using this mapstyle.withgoogle.com. But the thing that I'm not sure about, that I created a Text Document then changed the ending to .json, copied the JOSN code from google platform and put it there and then copied the file and put it in android studio. Because I couldn't know how to create a JSON file in android studio. I don't know if it sounds the right way to do that?

Comment: I have the same problem and I do the same steps as you, as of today could you solve it and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the previous comment that I left you, it was because I did not have the solution, but in reviewing the google documentation well I realized that there are two types of codes to implement the styles, one by JSON files and others by means of string

For the code that you show in the image it has to have a style_gray string resource, for this case I would suppose that you would have an xml file or that variable in the string.xml, you could use that same code like this:

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.raw.map_style_aubergine)));
```

For that error to be solved, you would have to implement this other code, which if it is compatible with JSON files in the format generated by https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/, the code would be the following:

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this,R.raw.map_style_aubergine));
```

In my case the `map_style_aubergine` is the JSON file and a variable in the string.xml you can use this as an example and make the respective corrections in your code